# Using superclass reference for grandchild subclass in Typescript

Tags: typescript, oop, design-patterns

I am working on a raycaster simulation with a TS backend. A subset of the class structure is in the image below (apologies for the quality of the "UML diagram").

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv7F4.png)

In another part of the project, I would like to store all of the items in the scene as an array of sceneItems, from which all of the items in the scene inherit (albeit not directly). For example, I have an object declared as

```
let myMirror: SceneItem = new FlatMirror(params...);
```

However, this throws the error `Type 'FlatMirror' is not assignable to type 'SceneItem'`. If I declare it with reference type `FlatMirror`, I can no longer include it in the array of `SceneItem`s since it is not of the correct type.

Is there a OOP solution or design pattern that will let me store objects in the scene together without using a large union type?

Thank you

Edit: Code for each class has been attached

```
//SceneItem.ts

export default abstract class SceneItem {
  abstract getNormal(point: number[]): number[];
  abstract intersectPoint(placeholder: Ray): number[];
  abstract newSegment(incident: Ray): RaySegment;
}

//ReflectiveItem.ts

import Ray from "./Ray";
import SceneItem from "./SceneItem";
import reflect from "../functions/reflection";
import { RaySegment } from "../types/RaySegment";

export default abstract class ReflectiveItem extends SceneItem {
  abstract getNormal(point: number[]): number[];
  abstract intersectPoint(ray: Ray): number[];

  newSegment(ray: Ray): RaySegment {
    const segment = ray.segments[ray.segments.length - 1];

    let incident = segment.direction;
    let intersect = this.intersectPoint(ray);
    let normal = this.getNormal(intersect);

    //const reflected: RaySegment = {
    const reflected: RaySegment = {
      direction: reflect(incident, normal),
      endpoints: intersect,
      intensity: segment.intensity,
      refractive: segment.refractive,
    };
    return reflected;
  }
}

//FlatMirror.ts

import ReflectiveItem from "./ReflectiveItem";
import Ray from "./Ray";
import inRange from "../functions/inRange";
import intersect from "../functions/intersect";
import normalize from "../functions/normalize";

export default class FlatMirror extends ReflectiveItem {
  //edge points of the mirror
  point1: number[];
  point2: number[];

  //normal vector to the mirror
  normal: number[];

  constructor(x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number) {
    super();

    this.point1 = [x1, y1];
    this.point2 = [x2, y2];

    this.normal = normalize([
      this.point1[1] - this.point2[1],
      this.point2[0] - this.point1[0],
    ]);
  }

  intersectPoint(ray: Ray) {
      //calculates intersect point
  }

  getNormal(point: number[]) {
    return this.normal;
  }
}
```

Comment: If your UML diagram represents subclasses, the assignment should be valid, and `FlatMirror` should be a subtype of `SceneItem`. The OOP approach is fine. Something is wrong with your implementation. Please [edit] your question to include the code of the three classes/interfaces, as well as the complete error message.

Comment: Please provide a working example on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review the guidlines for [ask], and in particular what makes a [mre].  Ideally you'll give us some small-ish bit of code we can drop into our own IDEs to see the problem you're seeing. That lets everyone work from the same starting point and test their potential solutions ahead of posting them.  Good luck!

Comment: @Dimava a playground link is a nice supplement but they need to at least provide a plaintext example directly in the question for it to be acceptable. (And while it's easy for one of us to go to the playground, copy that text, and paste it here, [that might violate copyright](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344484/pasting-fiddle-snippet-into-original-question-as-an-edit/344512#344512); code posted here is copyable, but code merely *linked to* from here might not be.)

Comment: [Trying to reproduce your problem](https://tsplay.dev/mxkAZN), it appears not to be a problem with the assignment of `myMirror` but rather simply that you didn't implement `intersectPoint` in `FlatMirror` yet: "*`Property 'intersectPoint' in type 'FlatMirror' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ReflectiveItem'.
  Type '(ray: Ray) => void' is not assignable to type '(ray: Ray) => number[]'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.`*"